# how to ORDER BY json object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to execute a query to give me 10 rows with the most biggest score ,column score in my table is a json object like :

```
{fa="7",en="7"}
```

how can i set my query to order by this json object ( it doesn't matter which of them (en or fa) used because they are always same )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json is  `{"fa"="7","en"="7"}` and assuming your json are in my_json_col  column  you could access  using a -> operator and order by

```
 SELECT * 
 from my_table  
 order by  my_json_col->"fa"
```

Comment: This requires MySQL 5.7.9 or higher, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path